# What is the IBAN of this Serbian account?

Tags: bank-account, money-transfer, international-transfer, iban

I need to pay 620 Serbian Dinars to "budget account No. 840-742221843-57, model number 97, reference number  59-013"

What is the IBAN of this account?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) states that the Serbian IBAN format is:

```
RSkk bbbc cccc cccc cccc xx
```

Wikipedia states that `bbb` is always `35`, but other sites make it clear that `kk` is always 35 for Serbia.  `bbb` is a bank code.  `xx` is calculated from the rest of the IBAN.  The 13 `c` elements are for the bank account number.

You need more information than what you have available to determine the IBAN:

- The bank account number 840-742221843-57 is 14 digits but a there is only space for 13 digits in the IBAN bank account number.
- You need the 3 digit bank code, and, according to this [Serbian Wikipedia page](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jedinstveni_identifikacioni_broj_banke), 840 is not the bank code as it is not listed as one of the Serbian bank codes.

Your best bet is to request the IBAN from the bank or have the recipient request it for you.

Comment: You mean to say that Serbian IBANs are constructed to circumvent the checks made in the IBAN system by always constructing the number in a way that `kk` is always 25?

Comment: Oh, it seems that even some more countries do this resp. have their own protection scheme. Very strange…